# Login without FOSuser

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to make a login form without FOSuser, as I need to override a lot in the entity User. I tried to find a lot of informations with the cookbook, and on several sites, but the mere informations were for SF2, which is quite annoying as the code may be different. 
I managed to make a registration form, which records the User on the db, but my login form doesn't want to work whatever I can do. I have only one error message, "Invalid credential". I thought it could be because of a bad algorithm, but I changed it three or four times (bcrypt, sha512, none...), no success.

Here's my security.yml (I know that there's a lot a useless code but I don't want to remove anything that could be useful):

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
        algorithm: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER


# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: FrontBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/register$
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: false
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check

        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /


        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        #   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html



access_control:

    - { path: ^/register$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here's my entity User (excuse my french, it's a school project :) ):

```
<?php

namespace FrontBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FrontBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mail", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $mail;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $photo;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=false)
 */
protected $roles;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entreprise", inversedBy="users", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entreprise_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $entreprise;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Promotion", inversedBy="users", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="promotion_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $promotion;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Annonce", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
protected $annonces;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Commentaire", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
protected $commentaires;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
protected $articles;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evenement", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
protected $evenements;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Evenement", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="evenement_user")
 */
private $participe;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Groupe", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="groupe_user")
 */
private $groupes;

public function __construct() {
    $this->participe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->groupes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->roles = array("ROLE_USER");
    $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
}



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set prenom
 *
 * @param string $prenom
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPrenom($prenom)
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prenom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrenom()
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

/**
 * Set mail
 *
 * @param string $mail
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setMail($mail)
{
    $this->mail = $mail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mail
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMail()
{
    return $this->mail;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set photo
 *
 * @param string $photo
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPhoto($photo)
{
    $this->photo = $photo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhoto()
{
    return $this->photo;
}

/**
 * Set ville
 *
 * @param string $ville
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setVille($ville)
{
    $this->ville = $ville;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ville
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getVille()
{
    return $this->ville;
}

/**
 * Set entreprise
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Entreprise $entreprise
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setEntreprise(\FrontBundle\Entity\Entreprise $entreprise = null)
{
    $this->entreprise = $entreprise;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get entreprise
 *
 * @return \FrontBundle\Entity\Entreprise
 */
public function getEntreprise()
{
    return $this->entreprise;
}

/**
 * Set promotion
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Promotion $promotion
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPromotion(\FrontBundle\Entity\Promotion $promotion = null)
{
    $this->promotion = $promotion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get promotion
 *
 * @return \FrontBundle\Entity\Promotion
 */
public function getPromotion()
{
    return $this->promotion;
}

/**
 * Add annonce
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Annonce $annonce
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addAnnonce(\FrontBundle\Entity\Annonce $annonce)
{
    $this->annonces[] = $annonce;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove annonce
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Annonce $annonce
 */
public function removeAnnonce(\FrontBundle\Entity\Annonce $annonce)
{
    $this->annonces->removeElement($annonce);
}

/**
 * Get annonces
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getAnnonces()
{
    return $this->annonces;
}

/**
 * Add commentaire
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Commentaire $commentaire
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addCommentaire(\FrontBundle\Entity\Commentaire $commentaire)
{
    $this->commentaires[] = $commentaire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove commentaire
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Commentaire $commentaire
 */
public function removeCommentaire(\FrontBundle\Entity\Commentaire $commentaire)
{
    $this->commentaires->removeElement($commentaire);
}

/**
 * Get commentaires
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getCommentaires()
{
    return $this->commentaires;
}

/**
 * Add article
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Article $article
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addArticle(\FrontBundle\Entity\Article $article)
{
    $this->articles[] = $article;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove article
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Article $article
 */
public function removeArticle(\FrontBundle\Entity\Article $article)
{
    $this->articles->removeElement($article);
}

/**
 * Get articles
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getArticles()
{
    return $this->articles;
}

/**
 * Add evenement
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $evenement
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addEvenement(\FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $evenement)
{
    $this->evenements[] = $evenement;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove evenement
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $evenement
 */
public function removeEvenement(\FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $evenement)
{
    $this->evenements->removeElement($evenement);
}

/**
 * Get evenements
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getEvenements()
{
    return $this->evenements;
}

/**
 * Add participe
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $participe
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addParticipe(\FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $participe)
{
    $this->participe[] = $participe;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove participe
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $participe
 */
public function removeParticipe(\FrontBundle\Entity\Evenement $participe)
{
    $this->participe->removeElement($participe);
}

/**
 * Get participe
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getParticipe()
{
    return $this->participe;
}

/**
 * Add groupe
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Groupe $groupe
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addGroupe(\FrontBundle\Entity\Groupe $groupe)
{
    $this->groupes[] = $groupe;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove groupe
 *
 * @param \FrontBundle\Entity\Groupe $groupe
 */
public function removeGroupe(\FrontBundle\Entity\Groupe $groupe)
{
    $this->groupes->removeElement($groupe);
}

/**
 * Get groupes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getGroupes()
{
    return $this->groupes;
}
public function getRoles() {
    return array($this->roles);
}
public function getUsername() {
    return $this->username;
}

public function getSalt() {
    return $this->salt;
}

public function eraseCredentials() {
    // Ici nous n'avons rien à effacer.
    // Cela aurait été le cas si nous avions un mot de passe en clair.
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set roles
 *
 * @param string $roles
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setRoles($roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}
public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword($password)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;
}
```

}

Here's my SecurityController:

```
namespace FrontBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('FrontBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}

}
```

Here are my routes:

```
login:
path: /login
defaults: { _controller: FrontBundle:Security:login}

login_check:
    path: /login_check
```

I think these are the only files needed to make it work, please tell me if you need anything else.

Thanks if you can help me :)

Comment: You forgot to encode password in registration controller before user is saved to db.